# increment variable each time function is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function fetchMoreListItems() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let n = 0
        setListItems([...Items.slice(n, n + 6)])
        n = n + 6
        console.log(n)
    }, 2000)
}
```

How to make `n` increment by 6 each time the function is called. I tried for-loop but it doesn't work with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Each time the function (either `fetchMoreListItems` or `setTimeout` callback)  is called `n` is set to 0. `n` will need to exist ***outside*** this callback in order to be updated each time function is called. Did you mean to use `setInterval` instead? Can you clarify your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, every time you run the lambda within setTimeout, you are recreating the n variable and then assigning to it. You should be creating the n variable before you call the function in order to maintain it's value between calls.

So, in your code:

```
    ... somewhere in your object / globally 
    let n = 0

    function fetchMoreListItems() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setListItems([...Items.slice(n, n + 6)])
                n = n + 6
                console.log(n)
            }, 2000)
     }
```

You need to clarify the use case for a more detailed response.

Comment: Between what calls? `n` is reset to 0 each time `fetchMoreListItems` is called.

Comment: the n value is 6 each time the funtion is called. its not incrementing

Comment: @DrewReese is absolutely right, I though setTimeout behaved like setInterval. If it's fetchMoreListItems that you call to increment n, you need to define n outside of the scope of that function. I've edited the response to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method would be moving let n =0 above the function fetchMoreListItems function.

**window.n = 0;**

But what you are trying to do in your in code is **JavaScript concept closure**

```
  let add = function (n) {
      return function () {
            setTimeout(() => {
            //setListItems([...Items.slice(n, n + 6)])
           n = n + 6
           console.log(n)
       }, 2000)
     }
   }
    
   let fetchMoreListItems = add(0);
   fetchMoreListItems();
```

Comment: i tried it. but im getting this error:  ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fetchMoreListItems' before initialization

Comment: I have pasted the above code in console. Its working fine for me. Did you initialize the function **let fetchMoreListItems = add(0);**  first and then called the function **fetchMoreListItems();** next?.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that each time `fetchMoreListItems` is called it "grabs" the next 6 elements from the `Items` array to copy into the `listItems` state, then you will necessarily need to keep `n` in component state and increment it each time. This appears to be basic pagination.

Increment the `n` state and use an `useEffect` hook to update the `listItems` state.

```
const [listItems, setListItems] = React.useState([........]);
const [n, setN] = React.useState(0); // <-- initially 0

React.useEffect(() => {
  setListItems(Items.slice(n, n + 6)); // <-- grab next 6 element chunk
}, [n]);

function fetchMoreListItems() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setN(n => n + 6); // <-- increment by 6
  }, 2000)
}
```